# What is the advantage of fixed heap size i.e. -Xms = -Xmx

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm

My application is using fixed heap size i.e. `-Xms` = `-Xmx` but even after some Googling I couldn't understand what is the advantage of fixed heap size. If any JVM expert could please throw some light on it.

Answer (score 2):

If you keep `-Xms` the same as `-Xmx` then a couple of things happen:

1. Right from the start you will get the same heap size committed to the virtual machine (JVM).
2. Since it is a fixed heap so JVM will never grow or shrink the heap, which is what usually happens after each GC cycle if `-Xms` is not same as `-Xmx`.

I am not sure if there is any real advantage in this but I think it is just that you get a controlled environment where you get a good heap size right from the start ([which is mentioned in the Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/memman.html)).

#### When you should use fixed heap size?

[From Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/gctuning/parallel-collector1.htm#JSGCT-GUID-31F3D722-5F93-41D6-817A-C6B91C095B6F): if you know the heap size requirement of your application then you should use fixed heap size otherwise you should go with either of the options - (1.) use `-Xmx` and `-Xms` (2.) don't use `-Xmx` and `-Xms`, and instead specify the garbage collector you want to use and it will grow and shrink the heap.